# Do I need to have Controller.php in all my API subversion?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes, controllers

I am trying to create an API directory in my Laravel project and I'm receiving the following error...

```
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Controller' not found
```

I have tried using `use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;` on top of my API controllers but no luck.

My API classes are defined like...

```
class SyncController extends Controller {...}
class TimecardController extends Controller {...}
```

I'm pretty sure the error is coming from the `extends Controller` portion.

in `App\Http\Controllers\Controller` I have `Controller.php`. One way I have pushed past this is to duplicate the `Controller.php` into `App\Http\Controllers\Api\v2\` and change the namespace of that controller to match where it is located (`namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\v2;`)

I don't believe this is correct, as there should be a way to reference the Controller.php from the controllers in the API subdirectory.

`../Controllers/Controller.php` and API is a subdirectory, `../Controllers/Api/v2/SyncController.php`

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

-----------Edit------------

my routes for the api look like so

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v2'], function () {
   Route::get('sync', 'Api\v2\SyncController@sync')->middleware('auth:api');
   Route::post('timecard', 'Api\v2\TimecardController@create')->middleware('auth:api');
});
```

Comment: Ensure the namespace of your class `Controller` is `App\Http\Controllers`. Then run `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: Did you change the namespace of Controller.php so it isn't App\Http\Controllers?  If app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php exists and you're receiving this error, you either screwed up that file or screwed up the composer autoload section.

Comment: share `App\Http\Controllers\Controller` file

Comment: here is the Controller.php  `
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
}
`

Comment: try `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: I will try composer dump-autoload. What about the controllers in my API directory, do I need to specify `use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;` ?

Comment: so I ran, `php composer.phar dump-autoload` and then tried to use `php artisan route:list` but still got the error `[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\v2\Controller' not found`

Comment: @Devon I didn't modify the namespace of the controller.php. My routes look like so `Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v2'], function () {
 Route::get('sync', 'Api\v2\SyncController@sync')->middleware('auth:api');
 Route::post('timecard', 'Api\v2\TimecardController@create')->middleware('auth:api');
});
`

Comment: extend `'App\Http\Controllers\Controller'` instead `'App\Http\Controllers\Api\v2\Controller'`, every controller needs to extend this

Comment: @Sohel0415  for the `..\Api\v2\TimecardController.php` and `..\Api\v2\TimecardController.php`, I have changed it to 

`namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\v2;`
`class TimecardController extends App\Http\Controllers\Controller`

with this I get ` Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Api\v2\App\Http\Controllers\Controller' not found` which I believe is because of the namespace of my api controller? ( `namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\v2;`)

Comment: Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Controller class cannot be found because the API controllers are not in the default Laravel controller directory. You need to add the controller class as a [use statement](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php). Then the autoloader will be able to find it.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\v2;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class SyncController extends Controller {...}
```

And while your at it you might also want to add the `auth:api` middleware to the entire group. Much safer and efficient.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v2', 'middleware' => 'auth:api', 'namespace' => 'Api\v2'], function () {
   Route::get('sync', 'SyncController@sync');
   Route::post('timecard', 'TimecardController@create');
});
```

Comment: This didn't work until I ran `php composer.phar dump-autoload` but spot on otherwise.Thanks .

Comment: Good to know about the middleware on the group. thank you!

Comment: @SegFaultDev Yes you can even add the namespace there as you can see.